# How can I run this in the background and launch 5 instances?

Tags: shell-script, background-process

```
cat /export/home/tmp/name_file.txt|while read line
do
        run -i name_file.tx $line  > /dev/null 2>&1
        address name_file.txt $line > /dev/null 2>&1
        sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to run the code snippet in your question five times in the background, then one easy way of doing that is putting the code into a file, `script.sh`, and executing it as a background job from a loop five times:

Assuming that you're using `bash` or `ksh93`:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do ./script.sh & done
```

That would be the easiest way.

Of course, the loop may go in the script itself:

```
#!/bin/ksh

for i in {1..5}; do
    cat /export/home/tmp/name_file.txt|while read line
    do
            run -i name_file.tx $line  > /dev/null 2>&1
            address name_file.txt $line > /dev/null 2>&1
            sleep 1
    done &
done
```

Here's an alternative, the way I would have written it:

```
#!/bin/ksh

for i in {1..5}; do
    while read -r name
    do
        run -i name_file.txt "$name"
        address name_file.txt "$name"
        sleep 1
    done </export/home/tmp/name_file.txt >/dev/null 2>&1 &
done
```

Comment: I'm sorry Ieft this out..  ( #!/bin/ksh)   So do I just remove everything else and use this only $ for i in {1..5}; do ./script &; done or do I add it to what i shared

Comment: I'm new to this so excuse me for my questions if it does not make sense to you.  I have created a file called name_file and I just want this to run 5 instances.  Where do I add this in the script or do I not?   $ for i in {1..5}; do ./script &; done

Comment: #!/bin/ksh                                                                                                 cat /export/home/tmp/name_file.txt|while read line
do
        run -i name_file.tx $line  > /dev/null 2>&1
        address name_file.txt $line > /dev/null 2>&1
        sleep 1
done

Comment: @suaveaz Sorry for the late reply, I had to sleep for a while. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I'm getting this error..../transGen[3]: syntax error at line 9 : `name_file' unexpected  Is it because, I'm using transGen?

Comment: @suaveaz I believe that error is unrelated to this question. I don't know what transGen is or how it is used. I also don't recognise the `run` and `address` commands, so I can't say if you're using them correctly or not.